# Finding all the pair of intersecting sets given n number of sets in a array

Tags: java, set, set-theory

Suppose we are given an arrayList of HashSets containing Strings. The problem is to print all the pair of the sets having non empty intersection.
The size of the list is n and each set is m.

The naive approach that I could think about was iterating through the array and checking with every element. This would take n^2*m complexity. n^2 for the for loops and m for finding the intersection for the set.

```
   void printPairs(List<Set<String>> sets){
        for(int i=0; i< sets.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j< sets.length; j++){
                //if Intersection is not null than print i andj
            }
        }
    }
```

I have not tried the code, but this should work. I am Searching for a better solution to this problem. This is the brute force Solution, Thanks.

Comment: first, build an index: element -> list of sets where the element is present. Then for every element in the index, generate all pairs of sets in the corresponding list if the list has more than 1 element

Comment: This looks like a reasonable Solution.

Comment: Time required to build the index would be m*n. We can keep the pairs in another hashset of pairs. this will massively improve upon the average case time complexity. But worst case would be the same(all the sets have same  Strings) = n^2*m.

Comment: what if we deduplicate the lists of connected sets before generating pairs?

Comment: the index itself looks like a bipartite graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph Maybe try to match it to a known problem?

Comment: I don't have knowledge about deduplication but will definitely have a look.

Comment: have you found an answer in the end? I'm curious